# Resize Unselected cell UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an UICollectionView with 9 visible items.

When I select a cell its width and height change but do not change all the other cells that are not selected.

I need that when I select a cell all the other unchecked ones need to disappear or have their frame in ZERO.

Also within my cell I have a button that returns the selected cell to the starting values ​​and in that case all the other cells must return to the original size.

Can anyone help me understand this?

**This is the code I use to expand the selected cell**

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *selectedIndex;

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if  (self.selectedIndex== indexPath) {

            // CELL SELECTED CHANGE SIZE
            return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width, collectionView.frame.size.height);
        } 

        // ORIGINAL SIZE 
        return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width/3, collectionView.frame.size.height/3);

}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.selectedIndex = indexPath;
    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: How about cells which isn't selected? Will they change position or size? ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    for (UICollectionViewCell* cell in collectionView.visibleCells) {
        if (cell.selected) {//leave only selected cell visible
            cell.hidden=NO;
        }
        else{
            cell.hidden=YES;
        }
    }
}
```

restore visibility on deselection

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    for (UICollectionViewCell* cell in collectionView.visibleCells) {
        cell.hidden=NO;
    }
}
```

very simple approach, just to give you an idea.

i.e. if your collection view is scrolling, you would probably handle the visibility of selected/unselected cells in

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(nonnull UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(nonnull UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```